# Use black instead of grey with ncurses colors on Gnome Terminal Ubuntu Gnome 14.04

Tags: c, colors, ubuntu-14.04, curses, gnome-terminal

If I use the use_default_colors() function, when I start_color() the background color of the terminal is not grey anymore, but black (The same I set in profile preferences), this is what I want because I don't like the grey. The problem is when I print something with color, the background color of the char I print is still the same grey.
It is not noticeable if I don't use the use_default_colors() function, because everything is grey.
But you can see it clearly if I use it. See screens

Is there a way to remove this grey and have it black, having a **portable** code? I want other people to see the same colors i set. For this reason I shouldn't be using use_default_colors() anyway, or maybe I can use it and change manually the background color with bkgd(); but I have the same problem. COLOR_BLACK is not actually black.

[With use_default_colors()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azRAa.png)
[Without default colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSU7z.png)

```
#include <curses.h>

int main (){
    int maxx,maxy;
    char test = '*';
    char test2 = '#';

    initscr();
    noecho();
    curs_set(0);

    start_color();
    //use_default_colors();

    init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(2, COLOR_CYAN, COLOR_BLACK);

    getmaxyx(stdscr,maxy,maxx);

    do{
        attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
        mvaddch(10,10,test);
        attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));

        attron(COLOR_PAIR(2));
        mvaddch(10,12,test2);
        attroff(COLOR_PAIR(2));

    }while(getch() != 'q');

    endwin();
    return;
}
```

Comment: I think you have you term set to have dark grey. Can you try `echo -e "\e[1;40m BLACK \e[0m"` ?

Comment: @Ôrel It shows the  word "BLACK" with the same grey background https://imgur.com/a/XPhkyeZ

Comment: 40m is the code for black background, if you get grey this is because your term configuration has a grey for black

Comment: use default instead of black can be what you are looking for

Comment: You can't make it "portable", because it's terminal-dependent.  GNOME-terminal uses color-palettes to make it look nicer (for some people).

Answer (score 1):

After invoking `use_default_colors()`, use `-1` in `init_pair()` to get the background color of the cells to match the default, instead of `COLOR_BLACK`:

```
init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, -1);
init_pair(2, COLOR_CYAN, -1);
```

On the other hand, if you want `COLOR_BLACK` to be really black, you could try redefining it via `init_color()`:

```
init_color(COLOR_BLACK, 0, 0, 0);
```

This isn't supported by all terminals, but should give pretty similar results where it is.

Comment: He can try - but gnome-terminal's default palette uses gray where one asks for black.  (kde konsole is worse in that regard, rendering neither white or black in a recognizable form).

Comment: He will get true black with the init_color() call above. (I just now tested it in gnome-terminal to be sure.)

Comment: See what happens when you do "reset".